# Looping through list of dataframes to calculate means

Tags: r

I am trying to loop through a list of sub-dataframes `list` to calculate a column of means for each, which I will append to an existing main dataframe `maindf`.

```
    list<-c(df1,df2,df3,df4)
    for (i in list) maindf$i<-rowMeans(i, na.rm=TRUE)
```

For some reason this gives me an error `'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`, but for a single dataframe, e.g. `maindf$df1<-rowMeans(df1, na.rm=TRUE)` it works.

Comment: Hard to tell without some example data and a desired result

Comment: Your code is wrong in many different ways. You named your list `list`, which is a bad idea. You also try to use a whole dataframe as the name of a new column, which can't work. And you do that using the wrong operator, `$` doesn't work for this situations because `i` wouldn't be evaluated, you should use `[[` instead.

Comment: Sorry if my code is unclear, I am extremely new to this! I am just trying to figure out why `maindf$df1<-rowMeans(df1, na.rm=TRUE)` adds a column of the row means of `df1` with the label `df1` to dataframe `maindf`, but the loop doesn't accomplish the same thing, even using `list()` instead of `c()`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you're trying to construct a list of data frames using `c`, which apparently doesn't work.  `c` ends up constructing a list where there is an entry for each column of the data frames `df1` and `df2`, rather than an entry for each data frame (see below).  Try using `list` instead.

```
> df1 = data.frame(a = rnorm(3), b = rnorm(3))
> df2 = data.frame(a = rnorm(3), b = rnorm(3))
> c(df1, df2)
$a
[1] -1.6372272 -2.2629156 -0.6714209

$b
[1]  0.9826798  0.4961860 -0.4499279

$a
[1] -0.2011259 -0.1115386  0.8568467

$b
[1] -0.2587402  0.1787140 -0.3563370

> list(df1, df2)
[[1]]
           a          b
1 -1.6372272  0.9826798
2 -2.2629156  0.4961860
3 -0.6714209 -0.4499279

[[2]]
           a          b
1 -0.2011259 -0.2587402
2 -0.1115386  0.1787140
3  0.8568467 -0.3563370
```

Comment: Even though this does solves one of the code's problems, it's really not an answer to the question, it doesn't even mention the "real" problem which is the loop/mean situation. It's clear that the author didn't check his code properly, since it contains several problems, so it would be better to wait until the question is improved to give an answer. This could be a comment (like my own).

Comment: I thought his question was about why the `rowMeans` function was complaining about its argument only having one dimension, and this is why.  But yes, there are obviously other problems.

Comment: I agree.  `lapply(c(df1, df2), rowMeans)` results in `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :   'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`, which is what the OP asks about

Comment: Your fix will solve that problem, but won't lead to this expected output. You can improve your answer if you create a fictional `maindf` and then write a proper loop, though IMHO this questions shouldn't be answered until the OP realizes he didn't understand concepts much more important than what's being asked.